# Not able to clone into repository on gitlab through port 80

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, networking, nginx, gitlab

I'm encountering a very weird issue with gitlab-ce installed on a server with ubuntu server (I've tried this with ubuntu server 16.04 and 17.04) , which runs on my local network. I'm using gitlab with apache2, with the following set up:

My /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb file looks as follows:

```
external_url "http://localhost:17391"
```

My apache virtualhost configuration file for the site (let's call it 'example.com') looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:17391
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:17391
</VirtualHost>
```

Essentially I'm taking the whole traffic apache is receiving and redirecting it to nginx. I can view 'http://example.com' in a web browser (I have to access the site through a proxy of course, because the server is running on the same local network as my pc) and everything works fine (signing in, viewing repositories, etc.). As soon as I try to clone into a repository on my pc by running the following command in a terminal I get an error message:

```
$ git clone http://example.com/user/repoName
Cloning into repoName...
fatal: repository 'http://example.com/user/repoName' not found
```

But when I try the same with the local ip of the server (let's say 192.168.1.100) instead of the domain it seems to work:

```
$ git clone http://192.168.1.100/user/repoName
Cloning into repoName
Warning: redirecting to http://192.168.1.100/user/repoName.git
remote: counting objects: 3, done
remote: total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done
```

So I thought that the reason it doesn't work might be that I can't access the server through the domain when I'm on the same local network.

Here is the weird part though:

When I try the exact same set up, but instead of port 80, apache listens on another port, 17392, both commands clone into the repo successfully.

Thank's for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I didn't find out what causes this weird behaviour, I found the solution to the problem (Actually: I found out there was not problem there in the first place).

I asked a friend to try to run the command

```
git clone http://example.com/user/repoName
```

and it worked fine. So it seems the process of cloning into a repo on port 80 works fine from outside the local network of the server, but from within the same local network, the local ip has to be used.